# "Carry something in for you" or "carry something for you"

Tags: prepositions

A line from the novel *The Fault in Our Stars*.

> Do you want me to carry it in for you?

Is it sufficient to say *carry it for you* instead of *carry it in for you*? What is the difference?

Comment: I am offering to carry it in from maybe car to inside the home, so 'carry it in' rather than carry it to nowhere special.

Comment: *Carry it in* is short for *carry it into the house/building*. It's not more correct nor less correct, but rather expresses a different offer--to bring the thing into the building, rather than to carry it to some unspecified destination. *Carry it in* may imply greater autonomy, where *carry it* usually implies that both parties will stay together, in my experience.

Comment: Please vote to migrate such questions to ELL. @YosefBaskin and please make those real answers, because they are answers.

Answer (score 2):

Mathieu K answered in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400273/carry-something-in-for#comment950680_400273):

> *Carry it in* is short for *carry it into the house/building*. It's not more correct nor less correct, but rather expresses a different offer--to bring the thing into the building, rather than to carry it to some unspecified destination.
>
> *Carry it in* may imply greater autonomy, where *carry it* usually implies that both parties will stay together, in my experience.

Comment: This was a community wiki answer I'd posted on ELU, but changed to normal answer here after migration. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Would you like it converted back into a wiki? You can just flag these for the mod team and we'll take care of it.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks, but not at the moment. There is a (possible) bug report I've raised in [meta ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10532/50044). Let this stay as is. I can convert it into CW any time by editing it.